# Difficult Integral in functional basis

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving, indefinite-integrals

Let $$g(x)=\int f\prime(x)\left[\frac{4}{3}x^2+4x^3+(2x^2+4x^3)f(x)+6x^2f^2(x)+xf^3(x)\right]dx$$
express $g(x)$ in terms of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,....\}$ and $\{f(x),f^2(x),f^3(x),...\}$.

Is there a clever way to solve this? I've tried integrating this many times with no useful result.

Comment: I am a bit worried by the $f'(x)$ as factor of everything. The derivative of $x\mapsto x^mf(x)^n$ is $mx^{m-1}f(x)^n+nx^mf(x)^{n-1}f'(x)$ and there is no term under the integral of the form $mx^{m-1}f(x)^n$. Are you sure that the expression is correct ?

Comment: Can you check your formula?  there are 6 terms in the integration, only the last term has $dx$ in it.

Comment: @mike: yes, you are correct. I fixed it. V.Rosseto: Yes, I am sure. I already found the answer, it is not possible to express $g(x)$ in those terms. It may seem disconnected, but one implies the other through certain algebraic manipulations. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171733/is-it-possible-to-express-int-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx1dx-in-elementary-fun